Pytorch and Matplotlib interfering
I'm facing a weird bug with Matplotlib and torch in my jupyter notebook. If I run with this torch.hub.load line the plt.imshow will simply not display anything (even tho frame is a correct image). If I comment this line the plt.imshow works.
Whether this torch.hub.load line is commented or not cv2.imshow will work.
onnx_path = "my_weights.onnx"
yolo_path = "lib/yolov5/"


torch.hub.load(yolo_path, 'custom', path=onnx_path, source='local') 

video_reader = VideoReader(str(src_file))

# wait for thread to read
while not video_reader.is_ready():
    waiting += 1
    time.sleep(1)

while(video_reader.is_ready()):
   frame = video_reader.frame

   #cv2.imshow('image',frame)
   #cv2.waitKey(0)


   plt.imshow(frame)
   plt.axis('off')
   plt.show()

It seems i'm missing something but I don't see it. Any help is appreciated :)

Thanks to @FlyingTeller, I was able to understand that the problem doesn't actually comes from Pytorch but Yolov5.
Reseting the backend didn't actually work ( instead of plotting, it printed <Figure size widthxheight with 1 Axes> )
So instead of resetting the backend to module://matplotlib_inline.backend_inline I put the following line in my notebook %matplotlib inline after loading the yolov5 model and it solved the issue

This is related to the matplotlib backend being changed by yolo, see this github issue. The solution should be to reset the matpltolib backend after loading:
onnx_path = "my_weights.onnx"
yolo_path = "lib/yolov5/"


# Save backend
b = plt.get_backend()
    
torch.hub.load(yolo_path, 'custom', path=onnx_path, source='local') 

#Reset backend
matplotlib.use(b)

video_reader = VideoReader(str(src_file))

# wait for thread to read
while not video_reader.is_ready():
    waiting += 1
    time.sleep(1)

while(video_reader.is_ready()):
   frame = video_reader.frame

   #cv2.imshow('image',frame)
   #cv2.waitKey(0)


   plt.imshow(frame)
   plt.axis('off')
   plt.show()


Since your answer isn't the actual answer I won't mark it as accepted but I wanted to thank you since it really guide me towards finding the correct solution quickly

You were welcome. Male Sure to include the Info hat You are in a jupyter notbekook especially for display related questions
